# IF Radio Button is checked and and no checkbox is checked then alert "please choose"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hey guys can you help me solve this problem. when  radio button value is "Reject" and checkbox1 checkbox2 checkbox3 is not checked then give alert "please choose reason"

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" value="reason1" id="checkbox1"> Reason1
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" value="reason2" id="checkbox2"> Reason2
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox3" value="reason3" id="checkbox3"> Reason3
<br>
<br>
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="Approve" id="radio1" required> Approve
 <input type="radio" name="radio" value="Reject" id="radio2" required> Reject
  <button type="submit" href="#"> Submit</button>
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)  You are expected to have made an attempt already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Let me know if you want an explanation.

```js
$('input').change(function () {

if($('#radio2').is(':checked') && $('#checkboxes input:checkbox:checked').length == 0) {
  alert("please choose reason");
}

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="checkboxes">
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" value="reason1" id="checkbox1"> Reason1
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" value="reason2" id="checkbox2"> Reason2
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox3" value="reason3" id="checkbox3"> Reason3
</div>
<br>
<br>
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="Approve" id="radio1" required> Approve
 <input type="radio" name="radio" value="Reject" id="radio2" required> Reject
  <button type="submit" href="#"> Submit</button>
```